# in rerofit i coundn't print JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-networking

In this code I will send id and mobile_no it retrieve me balance of user but it couldn't print in a `Toast`.

What am I missing here my work properly but I don't get response string

```
private void Get_Wallet_Amount() {
       Call<ResponseBody> call = AppController.getInstance().getApiInterface().getWalle_Data(Utils.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Const.PREFERENCE_USER_ID,""),
               Utils.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Const.PREFERENCE_MOBILE_NUMBER,""));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                String responseString = null;
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    responseString = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
//It doesn't print output

                Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, ""+jsonObject.getString("wallet_amt"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

> **Retrofit Interface**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("XXXX")
Call<ResponseBody> getWalle_Data(@Field("id") String uid,@Field("mobile") String mobile);
```

> **My JSON Output**

```
[
    {
        "wallet_amt": 50
    }
]
```

> **Error Logcat**
>   org.json.JSONException: Value [{"wallet_amt":50}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn.activity.Proceed_PaymentActivity$1.onResponse(Proceed_PaymentActivity.java:97)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-13 12:39:37.793 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   10-13 12:39:37.794 28522-28522/abc.example.com.rechargeappdesugn W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: It throws JsonParsingException. Check your logcat

Comment: is there any error message/ exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json` is `JSONArray` .

Use `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);` in your code .

> you have to use getString() instead of opString().

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        responseString = response.body().string();
        // edited here
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String wallet_amt = jsonObject.String("wallet_amt");
            Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, wallet_amt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: responseString = response.body().string();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
 //here i got a value 0 or null it coudn't show any thing                Utils.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString(Const.PREFERENCE_Walllet_Amt,jsonObject.optString("wallet_amt"));

Answer (score 0):

first of all you dont need to do any data manipulation related to response as retrofit internally handles this.
Please use following code snippet to get it working.

```
 class Wallet {
        @SerializedName("wallet_amt")
        private Long amount;
    }

Call<List<Wallet>> call = AppController.getInstance().getApiInterface().getWalle_Data(Utils.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Const.PREFERENCE_USER_ID,""),
                    Utils.getSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Const.PREFERENCE_MOBILE_NUMBER,""));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Wallet>> call, Response<List<Wallet>> response) {
                    String responseString = null;
                    try {

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Wallet>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(Proceed_PaymentActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```